# Removing html extentions and add trailing slash to files on all directories without affecting internal urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, trailing-slash, canonicalization

I am using the code in below to redirect index.html and non-www version of URL to www. It also removes *.html extensions from the files. Now, I would like to **add a trailing slash** at the end of the files across all directories. Following are the examples of what I want to get:

- www.mydomain.com.au/contact.html goes to www.mydomain.com.au/contact/
- www.mydomain.com.au/contact goes to www.mydomain.com.au/contact/
- www.mydomain.com.au/glass-replacement/Brisbane.html goes to
  /glass-replacement/Brisbane/

and so forth...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com.au$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.au/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index(\.html)?(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index(\.html)?$ /%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: So you want to redirect to `/foo/` if the user only requested `/foo`?

Comment: @CBroe Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^glassnow.com.au$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.glassnow.com.au/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index(\.html)?(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index(\.html)?$ /%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.glassnow.com.au/$1/ [R=301,L]
```